# htaccess & htpasswd not hooking up correctly

Tags: security, .htaccess, authentication, .htpasswd

Every time I try to go to [Art School](http://www.public.asu.edu/~rlpeck/CSE465a/art.htm) on  [Home Page](http://www.public.asu.edu/~rlpeck/) and put it the correct username/password I get a server error. Yes this is homework, and yes it is my first time doing anything related to this type of setup so any help would be appreciated. All the various instructions that I found listed this as the correct way so I'm sort of stuck.

.htpasswd file(`/afs/asu.edu/users/r/l/p/rlpeck/pwd/.htpasswd`):

```
Alice:$apr1$sgDEa/..$FBtlSGHkbPHmlW80Sj2Sx1
Bob:$apr1$V8LLa/..$iX.YVKHoDfKyTKEMvuX.g/
Chris:$apr1$XuHOa/..$o6bf/JyA1otkH0jor4n5c/
Dave:$apr1$hpjQa/..$u3/D.f0xdN23Flg35qp9g.
Eve:$apr1$JIGSa/..$uTs55qYH1.gtDV7WZ0X7q0
```

.htaccess file(`/afs/asu.edu/users/r/l/p/rlpeck/www/CSE465a`):

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /afs/asu.edu/users/r/l/p/rlpeck/pwd/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require valid-user
```

[image: Server Error]

When I do run  `locate -r error.log` all I get are these:

```
/opt/tivoli/tsm/client/ba/bin/dsmerror.log
/usr/share/doc/cups-1.2.4/de/images/button-view-error-log.gif
/usr/share/doc/cups-1.2.4/es/images/button-view-error-log.gif
/usr/share/doc/cups-1.2.4/help/ref-error_log.html
/usr/share/doc/cups-1.2.4/images/button-view-error-log.gif
/usr/share/doc/cups-1.2.4/ja/images/button-view-error-log.gif
/usr/share/doc/cups-1.2.4/pl/images/button-view-error-log.gif
/usr/share/doc/cups-1.2.4/sv/images/button-view-error-log.gif
/var/log/cups/error_log
/var/log/cups/error_log.1
/var/log/cups/error_log.2
```

Edit: Response from help desk:

> If you were testing the security of your page, you passed. I dont see an error

Comment: If you get a server error (a 500), there will be an `error.log` file entry telling you what went wrong.

Comment: Apparently I don't have access to the log file I sent an email to the helpdesk so I'll see if I get something back from them.

Comment: @Pekka posted a screenshot of the error Server Error I get

Comment: you'll need that line from the error log to know for sure what's wrong

Comment: @Pekka That is what I feared do my files look correct at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Is the .htaccess file being saved on the server using **UNIX line endings**? If you are saving it on a Windows computer, that is likely a problem. If you use FTP, you can transfer in ASCII mode. Otherwise, get a good text editor like Notepad++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and set UNIX format under Edit → EOL Conversion → UNIX Format.
- Is the **AuthUserFile pathname** correct? It should be the pathname that the web server computer sees, which might not be the pathname you see. You were probably logged in to a different server than the web server when you ran the locate command; the AFS network filesystem allows both servers to see your files but not necessarily at the same path on both.
- Does the web server **have permission** to read the .htpasswd file? Try putting it in the same directory as the .htaccess file and update the pathname in .htaccess accordingly. Of course, it depends on the server configuration whether or not the server will prevent someone from looking at the list of valid passwords that way, so you may need to figure out what AFS commands you need to use to grant such permission.

Comment: Created file while ssh-ed on the machine using pico.

Comment: The pathname I used was what printed when I ran `pwd` while in the same directory as .htpasswd

Comment: @Soldier.moth I have added another thing to check.